# How to put a jQuery click event on a checkbox in a grid in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am displaying a list of data in the following manner;
   
        
            
            
                Surname
            
            
                Forename
            
            
                Email Address
            
            
                Email Distribution
            
            
                Ops Manager
            
            
                Sign Off
            
            
                Admin
            
            
                Inputter

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Users) { %>

    <% Html.RenderPartial("UserSummary", item); %>

<% } %>

</table>
<div class="pager">
    <%: Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x=> Url.Action("List", new { page = x })) %>
</div>
```

and in the partial view;

```
   <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.UserId }) %> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=Model.UserId })%> |
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=Model.UserId })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Model.Surname %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Model.Forename%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Model.EmailAddress%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.EmailDistributionListFlag) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.OperationsManagerFlag)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SignOffManager)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.AdministratorFlag)%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.InputterFlag)%>
        </td>
     </tr>
```

I want to put a click event on each checkbox, so when the checkbox is clicked I can do a database update.
However I do not appear to have a unique client name for each checkbox.
So I would like to know how to put the click event on the checkbox, and how do I know which user row has been clicked in relation to the checkbox.

Comment: At the time of writing, the header columns are not being displayed in the above question. The partial view that you can see is placed with a foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the checkbox id this way:

```
Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.EmailDistributionListFlag, new { id = "checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag" })
```

And then you can access it by jquery:

```
$("#checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag").click(function(){ ... });
```

**Update:**

You missed a few brackets in your js:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
                  {
                      $("#checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag").click(function ()
                                         {
                                             alert("done!");
                                         }) // <-- Those were missing
                  });
```

And make sure you have jquery included.

**Update2**

To quickly create checkboxes with uniques Ids and bind a function:

```
Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.EmailDistributionListFlag, new
                         {
                             id = "checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag_" + Model.UserId,
                             onclick = "EmailClickFunc(" + Model.UserId + ");"
                         })
```

And you can define your `EmailClickFunc` in js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EmailClickFunc(id) { alert(id); }
</script>
```

Comment: I am not sure how I know with this click event what the UserId is. In any case I made the change and I put in the click event at the end of the partial view, and nothing happened;
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag").click(function () { 
                alert("done!");

        });
//]]>
    </script>

Comment: Check the generated Html first. Does the checkbox for EmailDirstributionListFlag has it's 'id' attribute set?

Comment: It does. However the ID is the same on each row (this is in a grid after all). I suspect the ID should be unique, but how do I make this happen?

Comment: As an experiment I tried with 1 row, but that did not work either.

Comment: Is it the UserId you are talking about? You can append it to the checkBox id value: Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.EmailDistributionListFlag, new { id = "checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag_" + Model.UserId }).
As a quick solution you can also try setting the 'click' function directly:
Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.EmailDistributionListFlag, new { id = "checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag", click = "EmailClickFunc(" + Model.UserId + ")" }), and define your function in js:
<script type="text/javascript">function EmailClickFunc(id) { alert(id); } </script>

Comment: I put the script at the bottom of the main page but no luck. I have tried putting breakpoints in Firebug but they are not being fired.

Comment: Can you post the generated page Html (for a one-row grid for starters)? It's usually easy to spot when analyzing that directly.

Comment: I will have to do this in parts, because of character restrictions in these comments.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
 
 List

</title><link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

Comment: <body>
    <div class="page">

    <table>
        <tr>

            <th></th>
            <th>
                Surname
            </th>
            <th>
                Forename
            </th>
            <th>
                Email Address
            </th>

            <th>
                Email Distribution
            </th>
            <th>
                Ops Manager
            </th>
            <th>
                Sign Off
            </th>
            <th>

                Admin
            </th>
            <th>
                Inputter
            </th>
        </tr>

Comment: <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/Users/Edit/0">Edit</a> |
                <a href="/Users/Delete/0">Delete</a>

            </td>
            <td>
                Smith
            </td>
            <td>
                Sue
            </td>
            <td>
                
            </td>

Comment: <td>

                <input click="TestClickFunc(0)" id="checkBoxEmailDistributionListFlag" name="EmailDistributionListFlag" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="EmailDistributionListFlag" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="OperationsManagerFlag" name="OperationsManagerFlag" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="OperationsManagerFlag" type="hidden" value="false" />
            </td>

         </tr>
 


    </table>

Comment: <div class="pager">
        <a class="selected" href="/Users/List?page=1">1</a>

    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function TestClickFunc(id) { alert(id); } 
    </script>


            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

Comment: You really should have posted this as part of the question ;)
But regarding the code - it's my bad, made a silly typo. Instead of "click = "EmailClickFunc(" + Model.UserId + ")", try "onclick = ...".

Comment: I will add the info to the answer then, hold on.